# How do I make buttons clickable in the bottom sheet fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, layout-inflater, android-viewbinding

**The flow: ** There are two xml files:

activity_main.xml
[image: activity_main.xml]

bottomsheet_fragment.xml
[image: bottomsheet_fragment.xml]

I want to click on "click here" button (xml id: btn_show) and show the bottom sheet fragment [This is happening correctly) .. corresponding files: activity_main.xml, MainActivity.kt

Now I want to click on the button in the bottom sheet(xml id: btn_button1), and show the text you pressed button 1 via toast(or anything else is fine too, I just want to show something when I click the button) [This part is not happenning correctly) .. corresponding files: bottomsheet_fragment.xml, BottomSheetFragment.kt

I am attaching codes for the files below:

bottomsheet_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="Sample button 1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

BottomSheetFragment.kt

```
package android.example.naruto

import android.example.naruto.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import android.example.naruto.databinding.BottomsheetFragmentBinding
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment

class BottomSheetFragment: BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var binding2: BottomsheetFragmentBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding2 = BottomsheetFragmentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding2.btnButton1.setOnClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(context, "You pressed on button 1!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click here"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

main_activity.kt

```
package android.example.naruto

import android.example.naruto.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import android.example.naruto.databinding.BottomsheetFragmentBinding
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding1: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding1 = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding1.root)

        val bottomSheetFragment= BottomSheetFragment()

        binding1.btnShow.setOnClickListener {
           bottomSheetFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, "BottomSheetDialog")
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help! Please let me know if you need any more details or clarifications.

I referred to these tutorials: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqnVPiWAw0o&t=21s, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GXflIdrlus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to see onCreateView method in `BottomSheetFragment`  and probably that's why it is not working

You can change your code like this

From

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding2 = BottomsheetFragmentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding2.btnButton1.setOnClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(context, "You pressed on button 1!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

To

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding2 = BottomSheetFamilyTreeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding2.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding2.btnButton1.setOnClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(context, "You pressed on button 1!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        
    }
```